# discord.py não mostra o avatar quando menciona

Tags: python, discord.py

Tenho um comando de avatar e ele mostra o '!avatar' e o '!avatar [id]', porém quando eu uso o '!avatar @user' ele dá esse erro:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.BadArgument: Converting to "int" failed for parameter "userid".
```

E eu queria que ele mostrasse o avatar de um usuário mencionado, se alguém puder me ajudar, serei grato.
Meu código:

```
@commands.command()
    async def avatar(self, ctx, userid: int = None):
        if userid == None:
            user = ctx.author
        else:
            user = await bot.fetch_user(userid)

        icon_url = user.avatar_url
        avatarEmbed = discord.Embed(title=f'{user.name}', description=f'**Clique [aqui]({user.avatar_url}) para baixar a imagem.**', timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(), color=discord.Color.dark_blue())
        avatarEmbed.set_image(url=f'{icon_url}')
        await ctx.send(embed=avatarEmbed)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você especificou que o argumento `userid` precisa ser um valor inteiro, logo, utilizar uma menção (`@fulano`) resulta em erro na conversão realizada pelo discord.py. Você tem duas opções:

1. Manter `userid` como inteiro e utilizar o comando especificando o ID do usuário, por exemplo: `!avatar 123456789`

ou

2. Mudar a assinatura para `userid` ser do tipo [`discord.User`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User). Nesse caso, você não precisaria dar um *fetch* no usuário pois você já terá acesso aos dados do mesmo, inclusive o [`avatar_url`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=user#discord.User.avatar_url). Ficando assim:

```py
@commands.command()
async def avatar(self, ctx, user: discord.User = None):

    if not user:
        return

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=user.name,
        description=f'**Clique [aqui]({user.avatar_url}) para baixar a imagem.**',
        timestamp=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
        color=discord.Color.dark_blue()
    )
    embed.set_image(url=user.avatar_url)

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Obrigado, ajudou muito